# 'cd' switch back and forth to previous and current directory

Tags: unix-shell

I found `cd -` can switch back and forth between previous and current directory which is a very handy feature. Also found `cd --` works too, but not sure what exactly that's for. Is there any reference covers this? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

I'm not clear if you are talking about  `cd --`, or `cd -- -`. So, I'll try to answer both questions.

`cd --` (with no directory) will act the same as `cd` (with no directory). You will be returned to your home directory. `cd --` will not switch you back to the previous working directory.

```
stefanl@host:~ $ cd tmp
stefanl@host:~/tmp $ cd --
stefanl@host:~ $ cd --
# Note that I do not go back to the directory ~/tmp
stefanl@host:~ $
```

See how that behavior is different from `cd -`. This is also true for `cd -- -`:

```
stefanl@host:~ $ cd tmp
stefanl@host:~/tmp $ cd -
/Users/stefanl
stefanl@host:~ $ cd -
/Users/stefanl/tmp

# `cd -- -` behaves the same as `cd -`
stefanl@host:~/tmp $ cd -- -
/Users/stefanl
stefanl@@host:~ $ cd -- -
/Users/stefanl/tmp
stefanl@host:~/tmp $
```

---

Regarding `--` for most Unix commands:

The `--` will tell `cd` to ignore any options after `cd --`. From the [Bash Man Page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands):

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented as accepting options preceded by ‘-’ accepts ‘--’ to signify the end of the options.

Pretend you had a directory called `-h` (Note that I need to use `--` here as well):

```
$ ls -ld -- -h
drwxr-xr-x  2 stefanl  stefanl  68 Nov  8 16:41 -h
```

You can't cd to this normally, because the command tries to interpret the `-h` as an option:

```
$ cd -h
-bash: cd: -h: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]
```

So use the `--` to tell cd not to process any more options after the `--`:

```
stefanl@host:~ $ cd -- -h
stefanl@host:~/-h $ pwd
/Users/stefanl/-h
stefanl@host:~/-h $
```

Comment: Are you sure about -- making it ignore arguments? It doesn't work for rm: `[james@aladdin blah]$ ls
hello
[james@aladdin blah]$ rm -- hello 
[james@aladdin blah]$ ls
[james@aladdin blah]$`

Comment: Ignore above, now you've filled it in I see what you mean, but it still doesn't work for cd. If you `cd -- -` it still takes you back to the previous directory, not -

Comment: @James : Arguments before the `--` are still interpreted. Arguments after the `--` are ignored.

Comment: That doesn't explain `cd -- -` being interpreted the same as `cd -`, unless the `-` is being passed as a path and *then* interpreted

Comment: @James, I'm a little confused if you are talking about `cd --` or `cd -- -`.

Comment: @Stefan I'm talking about both. If, as you state, `cd --` would cause any following arguments to be ignored, why is the `-` not ignored? Also, I'm not the OP :)

Comment: @James: `cd -- -` says don't process any *options* after `--`. It doesn't say don't process any *arguments*. So it's, in effect, the same as `cd -`.

Comment: @James: I guess `argument` was the wrong word. An `argument` is anything after the command (option flags, filenames, etc). A command `option` is something which is called with the dash symbols (`-h`). In the case of `cd -- -, the `-` is not a command option, therefore it is passed through to the command. I can't find anything which explains the mechanics well, so hopefully this will make my point clear.

Comment: @James :Sorry for mistaking you for the OP! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Previous directory is also `cd ~-`

Depends on your shell, but check out the `dirs` builtin (mine is `zsh` in this case):

```
[iluvatar]-[/srv/django]-[1126] % dirs -v
0       /srv/django
1       /srv/django/app
2       /srv/django/app2
3       ~
```

Then, you can use the `cd ~N` shortcut to change directories, as well as `pushd` and `popd` to change the stack.

Comment: +1 for mentioning pushd/popd

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to this for sure, but from what I've deduced it seems that the `--` is being interpreted as the precursor to an argument. As no argument is passed, it's being ignored and so defaults to `cd`, which takes you to your home directory.

It seems to happen for a few standard utils:
`[james@aladdin blah]$ pwd

/home/james/blah

[james@aladdin blah]$ touch hello

[james@aladdin blah]$ ls -

ls: cannot access -: No such file or directory

[james@aladdin blah]$ ls --

hello

[james@aladdin blah]$ rm -

rm: cannot remove '-': No such file or directory

[james@aladdin blah]$ rm --

rm: missing operand

Try 'rm --help' for more information.`